# How to simply delete duplicate records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have a few duplicate records. I want to simply delete them and leave one entry in the table.

Columns which matching is [SourceGradeId] from table A.

Can anyone show me a very simple delete query rather altering the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use row_number. This assumes there is another column or columns that help identify which to keep.

```
;with r as (
    select SourceGradeId, 
           row_number() over (partition by SourceGradeId order by <other col>) rn
    from A
 )
 delete r where rn>1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run below query to delete duplicate records based on "SourceGradeId" column form table A. 
**Be careful as this will delete many rows, take backup of your data before executing this**

```
With Duplicates as
(
   select * , row_number() over(partition by SourceGradeId order by SourceGradeId ) rownumber 
   from A  
) delete from Duplicates where rownumber!=1
```